# Manage IP whitelisting for Azure AppService with more than 512 IP addresses

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am managing an Azure App Service and need to add some IP addresses to the whitelist (under Network settings). We need to whitelist the IPs from a monitoring service which includes rather a lot of IP addresses (571 to be precise). Azure App Services have a limit of 512 IP addresses. What is the easiest way to get around this? Currently, our IP addresses are administered via a deployment script so we are not adding those IPs by hand.

Comment: Hi @MatthewDresser, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   Though the documentation for the app service IP restriction surely says as such so that `only 512 IP access restriction rules are allowed to be whitelisted from the networking access restrictions in an app service but it doesn't say that about IP addresses`. So, I tried to ***allow or whitelist a subnet of ‘/24’ or ‘65535’ IP addresses for an app service and I was able to do so effortlessly***. Kindly find the snapshot below for your reference: -

[image: App service restriction - 1]
[image: App service restriction - 2]
[image: App service restriction - 3]

Thus, the **documentation is correct, and it states regarding the limitation about access restriction rules not about IP addresses. As a result, any number of IP addresses can be whitelisted for an app service, there is no restriction on that**.

For detailed information regarding whitelisting the IP addresses for an app service, refer to the below documentation: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Multi-source rules to logically group the IP addresses into one rule. So theoretically the limit is (512 rules x 8 IP blocks)

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -WebAppName "AppName" -Name "Multi-source rule" -IpAddress "192.168.1.0/24,192.168.10.0/24,192.168.100.0/24" -Priority 100 -Action Allow
```